# Load Sharepoint page in a different web application

Tags: 2010

I am new to web development and SharePoint.
I want to display a SharePoint Page (which has reporting library) in a different web application which is not a SharePoint site.

1. Can I use an `iframe`, or `div`?
2. Can I pass user information to the loaded Sharepoint page?
3. What is the mechanism of doing it?
4. Can I pass the session data to Sharepoint page within the `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

1-) Yes you can use an `iframe`. But that's a very ugly hack and doesn't accomplish much.

2-) Only if the page with the `iframe` in it is in the same domain as the Sharepoint page.

3-) Javascript. And if you have to ask this, then unfortunately you are not up to the task of writing it (it's nowhere even close to simple).

4-) No.

Why do you want to use Sharepoint functionalities **outside** Sharepoint? You're headed in a way with too much wasted effort for some little worthless benefit at best.

My suggestion: there is a more elegant way to interact with Sharepoint if you don't want t navigate directly in it. Instead, use Sharepoint's built-in web services and RESTful API's to fetch and manipulate data. That way you can use your own UI. You will have to write a mountain of code anyway, but at least you'll be doing it like professionals do.

edit: it just came to my mind that you may want a page of yours to interact with a Sharepoint site. If that's the case, then again you should either have your custom pages in Sharepoint, or use the web services and REST API's.